# View Pdf and play video using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap 3.4.0 . What i want to do is to view pdf and video . I used InApp Browser which work for ios but in case of android it show blank page . I searched and found that we can view using the default reader but it is not feasible for me.Is there another way to solve it ??

Comment: You can try the webintent plugin for android.

Comment: thanks for your effort but it won't work for me !!

Answer (score 0):

for PDF you can go with MuPdf or Childbrowser.

Mupdf supports pagination also

Comment: i  tried child browser but it didn't work for my version i am using the latest version